# What's the best way to use Cargo to build for multiple platforms using the same source directory?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I frequently flip between my desktop and laptop, which have different operating systems. To coordinate, I like to keep my development / project directories stored in Dropbox.

Cargo will try to build to the same directory (i.e. `target/debug`) from both operating systems.  Ideally, I want a way that would allow me to automatically build to platform-specific build directories on each platform:

- `target/x86_64-apple-darwin`
- `target/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`
- `target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`

...or something similar.

Comment: Cross-compilation refers to building for a different platform than the one the compiler is running on.  What I'm looking to do is similar, but slightly different - in my case, I'm always compiling for the same platform that I'm building on... I just want to do that using the same source directory for both platforms.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend looking at out-of-tree builds.

If you have a project such as:

```
project/
    Cargo.toml
```

You can add a `.cargo` directory:

```
project/
    .cargo/
        config
    Cargo.toml
```

And put the following into the `config` file:

```
[build]
target-dir = "/tmp/build/dir"
```

As long as the path is valid for both operating systems, then each will point to a *local* build.

Plus... you'll avoid syncing MBs/GBs of binaries to your Dropbox account.

Answer (score 2):

I accepted [Matthieu M.'s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066868/920545) because it was elegant, functional, and made use of Cargo's features... but I realized that it didn't apply to my situation, where I wanted to sync between Mac and Windows, because Windows paths always start with, ie, "C:".

Also, I realized there's another easy way to solve this problem although it's Dropbox-specific:

Dropbox has a way to set files to be ignored, using file-system specific alternate streams / attributes.  Details can be found here:

https://help.dropbox.com/en-US/files-folders/restore-delete/ignored-files

(Note: I formerly recommended using Dropbox's "[selective sync](https://www.dropbox.com/help/syncing-uploads/selective-sync-overview)" feature, to disable syncing of the `target` directory, but they changed the way this works, so that you can't have a directory with the same name as your "selective sync" directory.)